# Saving a dataframe as a csv file(processed in databricks) and uploading it to azure datalake blob storage

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks, azure-data-lake

I had a csv file stored in azure datalake storage which i imported in databricks by mounting the datalake account in my databricks cluster, After doing preProcessing i wanted to store the csv back  in the same datalakegen2 (blobstorage) account.Any leads and help on the issue is appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just write a file in the same mounted location. See example from here: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/azure/azure-datalake-gen2.html#example-notebook

```
df.write.json("abfss://<file_system>@<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/iot_devices.json")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, got it, but it is saving the csv  file as a random name  , any help to save it as my own defined filename.Thanks for the help !

Comment: we can't write the file with specific name while writing into hdfs, using coalesce(1) generate a single file, rename the file once it is generated using command hadoop fs -mv *.something desired_name

Answer (score 0):

Just save it directly to Blob storage.

```
df.write.
    format("com.databricks.spark.csv").
    option("header", "true").
    save("myfile.csv")
```

There is no point in saving the file locally and then pushing it into the Blob.